# Why does the constructor return `Self`?

Tags: ink

From looking at the ink-examples I noticed that the `#[ink(constructor)]` always returns `Self`, in stead of emitting an event. Is there a reason behind it?

E.g. why does a simple `Ok(())` not do and emit an event?

Extending on that, it makes sense that an `#[ink(message)]` which only reads state, returns a value. However, considering an `#[ink(message)]` that mutates state, what could be the reason to return a value in stead of emitting an event?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think of `#[ink(constructor)]` as of normal Rust "constructor", e.g. a `fn new`. This creates the contract object itself. How that object is pushed on chain and whether event is emitted or not - is out of scope for the constructor. Its job is to create the contract object. If the constructor was supposed to only emit events then the responsibility to put the contract on chain falls to the constructor instead of its environment (substrate pallet?) as it is now.

re `#[ink(message)]` return values:

Returned values and events are two separate things:

- a returned value may be the message's primary way to communicate immediately to its caller that something happened
- an emitted event is an optional addition for historical purposes later on (I think)

Comment: Thanks! The `caller`, however, is not the one executing the message, it is a random node. And the node is not passing the return value back to the `caller` (for messages mutating state). So is there a reason for an #[ink(message)] (mutating state) to return a value within Ok(...)?

Comment: Returning values in messages is useful for cross-contract calling, without it, you would need to decode events. Events are useful for notifying frontend and 3rd party tools of any updates within the contract. Sometimes it is more gas efficient to emit the event upon mutation of storage and read it instead of having another message for reading the state.

Comment: Excellent, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`#[ink(constructor)]` in ink! is used to create contract instance and it needs to return the instance of contract to indicate that new instance has been created and initialized,[constructor_docs](https://use.ink/macros-attributes/constructor)

`#[ink(message)]` return value on contract invocation. [message_docs](https://use.ink/macros-attributes/message)

`Emitting events` can be used by third party tools to query information about contract execution and state. [event_docs](https://use.ink/basics/events)

Comment: To your first answer; but why not indicate that with an `Ok(())`? Second and third answer don't answer the question :)